# My container not becoming visible I think innerwidth, innerheight javascript code not written properly

Tags: javascript, css

I have a form container that I want to become visible triggered and centered in the middle of the window not the document, by a click.
My document container is 5000px height so I don't want it centered in that.
I have been searching but I am not very good. Here is what I have tried now.

```
.mrp-dynamic-form
{
position: absolute;
display: none;
background-color: blue;}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
$(".mrp-dynamic-form").attr('style', 'display:block;');
$(window).height() - $('div.mrp-dynamic-form').height()) / 2
$(window).width() - $('div.mrp-dynamic-form').width()) / 2
$(".mrp-dynamic-form").css('z-Index','30');    
});
});
</script>
```

No form even becomes visible anywhere with this.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have I written up my question wrong or not provided needed information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the opening '(' in your height/width positioning calculation which is causing a JavaScript error.  You are also not applying the calculated position to your .mrp-dynamic-form div (at least not in your example).  I fixed the syntax error and applied the calculated position to the .mrp-dynamic-form div:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        // keep the default behavior (navigate to a link) from happening
        event.preventDefault();
        // caculate the position that the .mrp-dynamic-form div should have
        let top = ($(window).height() - $('div.mrp-dynamic-form').height()) / 2;
        let left = ($(window).width() - $('div.mrp-dynamic-form').width()) / 2;

        // apply the css styles to position the .mrp-dynamic-form in the center of the window regardless of where you are on the page
        $('.mrp-dynamic-form').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'display': 'block',
            'top': `${top}px`,
            'left': `${left}px`,
            'z-index': '30'
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.mrp-dynamic-form {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="height: 5000px">
    <a href="">Click</a>
    <div class="mrp-dynamic-form">
        <form action="">
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="John">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have been working for a week on this and hoped to answer my own question by tomorrow.  I used console.log to see what was working and what wasn't. also saw that I didn't even have semi colons where I need. It is a lot to learn and I am not trying to get free easy info. Thank you very much. It is appreciated.

Comment: @geddeca [JSHint](https://jshint.com) is a helpful tool especially if you are just learning.  Many IDEs can incorporate it or [JSLint](https://www.jslint.com) as a plugin which allows you to lint your code as you write it.  If this answer helped you, please upvote it and if it answered your question, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I would love to accept your answer as ANSWER  but I don't know how.  Please let me know how and I will do it.

Comment: @geddeca Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. "